# How to get custom post category?

Tags: wordpress

So I have a custom post type with a custom category: 'destination'. Each post has various destinations to choose from and I have a form on these single post pages. I have a select form field in my form and what I want to do is to populate that select field by getting the selected post categories for that particular post.

Here's the code I tried and its not working. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );


  $select = "<select name='cat' id='cat' class='postform'>n";
  $select.= "<option value='-1'>Location</option>n";

  foreach($categories as $category){
    if($category->count > 0){
        $select.= "<option value='".$category->slug."'>".$category->name."</option>";
    }
  }

  $select.= "</select>";

  echo $select;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get list of custom categories of a custom post you will need to use get_the_terms() as explained here:

get_the_terms( $post_id, 'destination' );

Comment: That's exactly what I was wanting. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :) Please don't forget to approve the answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks again